# Microsoft Graph Group Member Least Privilege

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My objective is the least privilege principal in MS Graph (v1.0). The MS Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions) categorically state that **Groups.Read.All** is an acceptable permission. However, I get no result when I make the following call:

`var members = await graphClient.Groups[groupID].Members.Request().GetAsync();`

The only way I get the correct result is by using the **Directory.Read.All** permission, which just has to be a higher level of privilege.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Container objects such as groups support members of various types, for example users and devices. When an application queries the membership of a container object and does not have permission to read a certain type, members of that type are returned but with limited information. The application receives a 200 response and a collection of objects. Complete information is returned for the object types that the application has permissions to read. For the object types which the application does not have permission to read, only the the object type and ID are returned.

This is applied to all relationships that are of directoryObject type (not just member links). Examples include /groups/{id}/members, /users/{id}/memberOf or me/ownedObjects.

For example, let's say an application has User.Read.All and Group.Read.All permissions for Microsoft Graph. A group has been created and that group contains a user, a group, and a device. The application calls list group members. The application has access to the user and group objects in the group, but not the device object. In the response, all the selected properties of the user and group objects are returned. For the device object, however, only limited information is returned. The data type and object ID are returned for the device, but all other properties have a value of null. Apps without permission will not be able to use the ID to get the actual object.

**To read the group memberships of a user (memberOf), the app must have either Group.Read.All or Group.ReadWrite.All. However, if the user also has membership in a directoryRole or an administrativeUnit, the app will need effective permissions to read those resources too, or Microsoft Graph will return an error. This means the app will also need Directory permissions, and, for delegated permissions, the signed-in user will also need sufficient privileges in the organization to access directory roles and administrative units**.